# SQL - Eliminate duplicate rows in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a bit of a novice here and I'm trying to write a query that will show me one parcel for every distinct Tax District.

Here is what I have

```
SELECT TaxDistrict, Parcel
FROM Property 
WHERE TaxYear = 2019 AND Roll = 'RE' AND TaxDistrict > '9000'
```

This returns me something like this:

[image]

What I want is to select just one parcel from each distinct TaxDistrict and It doesn't matter what parcel it is. I've tried `SELECT DISTINCT TaxDistrict, Parcel` but since every parcel is distinct as well that doesn't get me anywhere.

What I want is something like this:

[image]

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT TaxDistrict, MIN(Parcel)
FROM Property 
WHERE TaxYear = 2019 AND Roll = 'RE' AND TaxDistrict > '9000'
GROUP BY TaxDistrict;
```

Comment: I knew this was something simple. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use "group by" with min() function like below:

```
SELECT TaxDistrict, min(Parcel)
FROM Property 
WHERE TaxYear = 2019 AND Roll = 'RE' AND TaxDistrict > '9000'
GROUP BY TaxDistrict
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this one.

```
SELECT TaxDistrict
    ,MIN(Parcel)
FROM Property
WHERE TaxYear = 2019
    AND Roll = 'RE'
    AND TaxDistrict > '9000'
GROUP BY TaxDistrict
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved a case like yours using:

```
...
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Column 1, column 2...
            ORDER BY Column 1, column 2...
        ) row_num
```

An example [here](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/delete-duplicates-sql-server/)